# mysql query: display all entries from guestbook_comments for a specific owner_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with query from multiple tables.

**My database:**
I have following tables:

```
1. users (user_id, user_name, ..) //user_name is unique.
2. guestbook_comments(owner_id, comment_author_id, comment ..)
3. profile_photo(profile_photo_id, user_id, path)
```

**My problem:**
I want to build a following query:

1. I have url like `guestbook.php?user=sudeep`. So i get `user_name` by `$_GET['user'];` `user_name` is unique (in the users table).
2. I want to display all entries from `guestbook_comments` for a specific `owner_id` (but i only know `user_name`, so i will need to find `user_id` from `users` table).
3. For each of the `comment_author_id` in `guestbook_comments` table, I want to get the his `user_name` from table `users` and `path` from `profile_photo` table.

**My approach:**
First I join users and guestbook_comments table to get all guestbook comments for a specific user_id. Then In the `while loop` I join `users` and `profile_photo` table to get `user_name` and photo `path` respectively.

I highly doubt if my approach is any efficient. Can you tell me if there is a right way to do that?

```
 $sql = "SELECT u.user_id, g.owner_id, g.comment_author_id
FROM guestbook g
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = g.owner_id
WHERE u.user_name = $user_name";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {        
        $author_id = $row['comment_author_id'];
        $sql = "SELECT u.user_name, p.path
                FROM profile_photo p
                INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = p.user_id
                WHERE u.user_id = $author_id;

                //display comment text from guestbook, user_name from users, and photo from profile_photo
    }
```

Comment: It all looks good? What is your issue? is your SQL query failing?

Comment: @Craig White, As i said I would like to know if there is a better and more efficient way to do it, because i'm not expert and I doubt if it is an efficient approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a single query:

```
SELECT u.user_id, g.owner_id, g.comment_author_id, g.comment_text, c.user_name, p.path
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN guestbook g
    ON u.user_id = g.owner_id
LEFT JOIN users c
    ON c.user_id = g.comment_author_id
LEFT JOIN profile_photo p
    ON p.user_id = g.comment_author_id
WHERE u.user_name = $user_name
```

From user, find guestbook entries, find commenters, find commenters' photos

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something, or could you combine both joins at once and get all the data with 1 call to the database, rather than 2 calls per user?

```
 $sql = "SELECT u.user_id, g.owner_id, g.comment_author_id, p.path
FROM guestbook g
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = g.owner_id
INNER JOIN profile_photo p on u.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE u.user_name = $user_name";
```